# UIImagePickerController Problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, controller

I've come across a rather weird bug in `UIImagePickerController`. (or I'm doing something wrong)

I load the controller as such:

```
    UIImagePickerController*controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [controller setDelegate:self];

    [firstView presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Now the problem is the following: The code works great, but only once. It's tied to an `UIButton` as an action - if I click it the second time instead of the `UIImagePickerController` I get a translucent (alpha 0.8ish?) black view appearing, which I can't dismiss.

I create no such view anywhere, it's only the `UIImagePickerController` that is in that action.

I dismiss it in the delegate:

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
    {
        [firstView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
```

and this works as it should as well.

What am I doing wrong / is this a bug?

Comment: kind of really weird, maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Try to clean all targets from build menu.

Comment: cleaning does not change anything - still the same problem. @vodkhang - It's only in an IBAction and the code above is the only code in it, so it cant be something else...

Comment: probably just **delete** this question, since it turned out to be **utterly unrelated** to UIImagePickerController

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is release the controller after the present:

```
UIImagePickerController*controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[controller setDelegate:self];
[firstView presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
// Here...
[controller release];
```

And not in the did finish:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [firstView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // Not here...
    //[picker release];
}
```

The `presentModalViewController` will retain the controller for the duration and release it appropriately.

Comment: I have now found the problem. It actually was in the `UIActionSheet` that triggered the `IBAction`. It seems like `showFromTabBar:` only works once in the 4.2 SDK, then the Action Sheet no longer appears - seems to be a bug. Thanks for the help!

Comment: release it before or after doesn't make any difference